# Games animation stopped working the way it should - corona SDK

Tags: ios, lua, coronasdk

So....Something weird has happened with my game. In my game theres 2 sequences for animation: Hop and Drop

```
local sequenceData = {
    {name="hop", start=1, count=1, time=300},
    {name="drop", start=2, count=1, time=300}
}
```

Theye are called from a function called 'MovePlayer()

```
function movePlayer(event)
   bird.bodyType = "dynamic"
   gameStarted = true
   if event.phase == "began" then 
        bird:setLinearVelocity(0, -flapForce)
        playSFX(sndJump)
        bird:setSequence("hop")
        print("Hop")
   elseif event.phase == "ended" then
        bird:setSequence("drop")
        print("Drop")
   end
   return true
end
```

These worked fine before but now I don't see any of the animation when I tap the screen and expect the hop sequence to play out. Any idea whats wrong? The game is was created way back in April.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`After changing the sequence, the sprite will not play automatically — call object:play() to continue playing on the new sequence.`

[Corona Docs](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/SpriteObject/setSequence.html)